# Sas .dat file without column headings only 1st row being read in sas studio

Tags: sas

I'm using Sas studio university edition. I have a dat file without any column headings (4 columns). I'm trying to read it in with

```
data van;
    infile "/folders/myfolders/test2/psek-win.dat";
    input a $ b $ c $ d $;
run;
```

i.e. create my own names for the columns. It works, but only the very first line is being read in. How can I get it to read all lines? I have been watching youtube tutorials but I'm stuck.

EDIT: Here is the output

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 57         
 58         data van;
 59             infile "/folders/myfolders/test2/psek-win.dat";
 60             input a $ b $ c $ d $;
 61         run;

 NOTE: The infile "/folders/myfolders/test2/psek-win.dat" is:
       Filename=/folders/myfolders/test2/psek-win.dat,
       Owner Name=sasdemo,Group Name=sas,
       Access Permission=-rw-rw-r--,
       Last Modified=05Jun2015:06:55:44,
       File Size (bytes)=1527

 NOTE: 1 record was read from the infile "/folders/myfolders/test2/psek-win.dat".
       The minimum record length was 1527.
       The maximum record length was 1527.
 NOTE: The data set WORK.VAN has 1 observations and 4 variables.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.01 seconds
       cpu time            0.01 seconds


 62         
 63         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 75
```

EDIT 2:
I really should have included this info from the start...sorry:
I'm using Windows 7, running Sas Studio through VirtualBox on Linux Redhat 64. I realized the file I was using was meant for Windows. When I use a Linux version of the same file it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in the log?

Comment: Are you sure this is SAS dataset? For window OS, after SAS8, SAS data file is .sas7bdat, and if is is SAS data, you could read directly not need infile and input.

Comment: Added the output, will try the solutions proposed below when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: @LXandor Just to be clear, is 1527 the expected line width for this file, or are you expecting something much shorter?  And can you update with your OS?  And when you open the file in notepad/etc., do you see multiple lines - or do you have a different reason to believe the lines are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the file I was using was meant for Windows. When I use a Linux version of the same file it works fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, if SAS is only reading one line and then acting as if it were done when it has many lines, it is a problem with the line terminator (ie, the end-of-line character(s)).

Windows uses CR+LF (`0D0A`) while Unix/Linux use `0A` (LF), including Mac OS X.

This means that if you're on a Windows machine and have a Unix terminated file, it will be read in as if it has only one line.  The other way around usually isn't a problem - you get an extra character that might make a bit of a mess, but it still acts as if it were the right number of lines.

You can alter this in the datastep by specifying the [`termstr=`](http://support.sas.com/kb/14/178.html) option to specify the correct line terminator.  So for example:

```
data van;
    infile "/folders/myfolders/test2/psek-win.dat" termstr=lf;
    input a $ b $ c $ d $;
run;
```

Would instruct SAS to consider a simple line feed to be a line terminator.

Comment: Note that University Edition is run in a VM, so I would not assume that the OS you're running locally is equivalent to the OS the VM is running.  I think the VM is running Linux, but SAS may make some changes to how things work in order to accommodate Windows users.

Comment: I think you're right about this. I recall writing csv files with University Edition which when viewed in notepad, don't display the line breaks. Presumably, this is because notepad looks for CR, LF.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure, actually, because my gut feeling is it should be backwards.  If the file originated in Windows and is run in a Linux SAS UE, it should have line breaks (just extra CR junk).  So it's a bit odd.  But I've never seen this problem (only reads in one line) have any other source than bad TERMSTR.

Comment: So maybe he needs `termstr=crlf` to read a windows file on a unix machine?

Comment: Well, yes, technically, but the thing is if you're reading a windows file on a *nix machine it will still read as the right number of lines (since LF is there).  Just the last field on the line will be corrupted by the CR character which is read in as a regular character.  That's not what the OP is reporting - in fact, the reverse is consistent with what OP is reporting (a *nix-created file being read on a Windows machine) would have this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I will read through this and give it a go when I get home. In the meantime I've added the output to the original past.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then try adding `put _infile_ $HEX512.` before the run, and see what shows up.  See if after your believed line you have a `0D0A` or just `0A` or none.